# Does SQL Server Management Studio come with Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, ssms

I have the full Visual Studio 2010 (not express) installed, with SQL Server that came with it as well:

[image]

I was trying to locate SQL Server Management Studio ([ssms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Management_Studio)) in order to follow [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OJfYSZzZOP8) but I can't seem to find it in my installation.

I could theoretically download the [2008 Management Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7593) but given the so many editions and versions of SSMS (e.g. [2012 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062)), how do I know whether it is compatible with my VS 2010?

Also, why download an Express Edition if I already have it in my original Visual Studio 2010 DVD?

So my questions are:

1. Is SSMS already installed but I don't see it? (if so, how do I locate it?)
2. If it's not installed, do I just need to run Setup again, then install it?
3. If it isn't really on the VS 2010 DVD (as many on SO suggest), which downloadable Express edition is most compatible with my VS 2010 (not express)?

**Update:** (for the benefit of future MS SQL Server newcomers)

Thanks to the answers below I managed to successfully install what I needed and most importantly **understand** the tools picture.

So to answer my particular questions one by one:

1. No
2. No
3. SQL Server Management Studio **2008** Express

**Tips:**

1. Once everything is installed, the next question is *"What do I do next?"*. Fortunately, there is a [great tutorial](http://www.functionx.com/sqlserver/Lesson03.htm) which to me is much clearer than the cumbersome (repetitious, cyclic links, non-linear, etc.) [official Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500434%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).
2. Despite the greatness of the functionx.com tutorial, it doesn't provide enough details on how to initially connect [to local](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360141/how-to-connect-to-local-instance-of-sql-server-2008-express). Once again, SO comes to the rescue and clarifies that 2 more conditions must be met: **(a)** SQL Server [Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10421827) service must be running. **(b)** Server name must not be "local" but rather `<local-pc-name>\SQLEXPRESS`.
3. To programmatically create a database in C#, use [ADO.NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307283) as well.
4. [Why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529142/what-good-are-sql-server-schemas) use schemas.
5. Don't even think about storing database files on a [network share](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11954379/1731850).
6. If you get "Invalid object name" in a SELECT statement for a table you just created, [refresh the local cache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1362575/1731850).
7. When encountering `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException` for the first time you use C# with an existing database using `new SqlConnection()`, remember that "Data Source=" cannot specify the computer name alone (as in the tutorial) but rather have \SQLEXPRESS appended to the computer name. Also, make sure [TCP/IP Client Protocol](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/) is enabled.

Comment: I don't agree with the downvote and the close vote. The question is related to development tools, and thus, satisfying the site expectations.

Comment: @SteveB Thank you. Some folks on SO don't seem to understand the value of SO as "better than Google", especially for beginners in a certain field.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

SSMS is for running queries and performing database administration tasks, etc. Configuration manager is a configuration tool for SQL Server, where you can configure (Start/Stop/user credentials, etc.) the services used by SQL Server.

However, installing Visual Studio does not mean you get the full version of SQL Server, but you get the Express edition, which does not include SSMS.

Maybe [this MSDN link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2011/02/18/step-by-step-installing-sql-server-management-studio-2008-express-after-visual-studio-2010.aspx) will help.

Comment: OMG You are an angel. That's exactly the kind of link I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

As said by bugfinder and others (+1 to all) sql management studio and sql configuration manager are not the same.

It doesn't matter which visual studios version you have.

What matters is the sql server version you have. I.e
 You have sql server 2008 installed thus you should download management studio for sql server 2008. ( you have the link in your question). I have vs 2010 ultimate and it didn't have management studio incorporated.

Comment: Thank you. I am beginning to understand the picture. +1.

Answer (score 3):

No configuration manager is for configuring how your SQL server allows connections. There is still an "SQL Server Management Studio" for queries etc

Comment: Thanks (and upvote) for at least clarifying this confusing situation. Does SSMS come with the VS DVD?